# Django admin: using inlines through a non-adjacent ManyToMany relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

Consider the following `models.py`, where a Group contains multiple Persons who each have zero or more Phone numbers. In this particular case, Persons who share a Group will often share at least one Phone number, so a many-to-many relationship is used.

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Person(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Phone(models.Model):
    persons = models.ManyToManyField(Person)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

I would like to show these models in the Django admin, in a single view, as shown below.

```
class PersonInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Person

class PhoneInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Phone # also tried: Phone.persons.through

@admin.register(Group)
class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PersonInline, PhoneInline]
```

However, there is no foreign key between Group and Phone, so this raises a `SystemCheckError` (one of the following):
`<class 'myapp.admin.PhoneInline'>: (admin.E202) 'myapp.Phone' has no ForeignKey to 'myapp.Group'.`
`<class 'myapp.admin.PhoneInline'>: (admin.E202) 'myapp.Phone_persons' has no ForeignKey to 'myapp.Group'.`

Is it possible to make this work through the Person model? The goal is for the Phone inline to show phone number records for all Persons in the Group (bonus: when adding a new Phone, the Person SelectMultiple widget will need to only show other Persons in the Group). I would prefer to avoid modifying any templates. A third-party app could be integrated if necessary. I can use Django 1.10 or 1.11.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by slightly modifying my requirements. Rather than requiring a relationship between `Phone` and `Person` only, I added another many-to-one relationship: between `Phone` and `Group`. For my particular case, it actually works out better this way; and a `Group` should cascade to both related `Person`s and related `Phone`s on delete.

There is no change to the `admin.py` shown in the question. The `models.py` has one more line in the `Phone` class, a ForeignKey field:

```
class Phone(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    persons = models.ManyToManyField(Person)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

---

The "bonus" above requires that the ManyToManyField form widget in the `Person` inline show only those `Person`s that are in the same `Group`. For this, two functions can be added to `admin.py`:

```
class PersonInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Person

class PhoneInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Phone

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        field = super(PhoneInline,
                      self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request,
                                                     **kwargs)
        if db_field.name == 'persons':
            if request._obj_ is None:
                field.queryset = field.queryset.none()
            else:
                qs = Person.objects.filter(group=request._obj_.id)
                field.queryset = qs
                field.initial = qs
        return field

@admin.register(Group)
class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PersonInline, PhoneInline]

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        # Save obj reference for future processing in Phone inline
        request._obj_ = obj
        return super(GroupAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```